# Add owl carousel instead of posts thumbnails in WordPress archive loop

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, owl-carousel

I am working on a Wordpress theme that has implemented a gallery meta field for each post's content. I would like to use images from this gallery to add an owl-carousel instead of post's thumbnail on archive page.

The main problem is that inside my loop i will wrap my carousel in the owl div and give it an id dynamically that will be related with the current post's id `id="owl-archive-<?php the_ID();?>"` so it will be unique for each post that appears on archive. Then i must call also dynamically owl-carousel function in my js file for each one of these id and this is my problem.

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
 while ( have_posts() ) {
  the_post(); 
  //carousel starts
  <div id="owl-archive-<?php the_ID();?>" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <?php foreach ($gallery_ids as $gallery_id): $gallery_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($gallery_id,'full'); ?>
      <div class="item">
       <a class="noo-lightbox-item" data-lightbox-gallery="gallert_<?php the_ID()?>" href="<?php echo $gallery_image[0]?>"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $gallery_id, 'full' ); ?></a>
      </div>
    <?php endforeach;?>
  </div>
 //carousel ends
 }
}
```

How can i call dynamically my id from `owl-archive-<?php the_ID();?>` instead of  `#owl-archive`

```
    $("#owl-archive").owlCarousel({
      navigation : false,
      slideSpeed : 300,
      paginationSpeed : 400,
      singleItem:true,
      autoPlay:true,
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it with the most simple way. The [data attr](https://api.jquery.com/data/).

```
    <div data-archive="<?php the_ID();?>"  id="owl-archive-<?php the_ID();?>"
```

And then my js

```
    $('.owl-carousel').each(function(){
    var the_id = $(this).data('archive')
    $('#owl-archive-' + the_id).owlCarousel({
      navigation : false, 
      slideSpeed : 300,
      singleItem:true,
      autoPlay:false,
      navigation:false,
      pagination:false,
      lazyLoad : true,
      autoHeight : true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wp_localize_script()`,  this function is used to handle php variables  in a js file.

You can read more and find all what you need [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)

Hope it helps!